# Complete a YAML file with a python script interactively

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to complete a yaml file with a python script. I want to ask some questions from a user through a python script to complete the yaml file.
this is my yaml file:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: **Groeifabriek**
    Domain: **groeifabriek.nl**
    EnableNodeOUs: **true**
    Specs:
      - Hostname: **orderer0**
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: **Karga**
    Domain: **aptalkarga.tr**
    EnableNodeOUs: **true**
    Template:
      Count: **1**
    Users:
      Count: **1**
  
  - Name: **Nevergreen**
    Domain: **nevergreen.nl**
    EnableNodeOUs: **true**
    Template:
      Count: **1**
    Users:
      Count: **1**

  - Name: **Atlantis**
    Domain: **atlantis.com**
    EnableNodeOUs: **true**
    Template:
      Count: **1**
    Users:
      Count: **1**
```

I have made a script to ask only the fist part of yaml file to test the script, but it doesn't work and I get an error.
How can I fix it? How can I write a script to complete all data required in yaml file?
This is my script:

```
import yaml

file_name = 'crypto-config1.yaml'

with open(file_name) as infile:
    data = yaml.load(infile)

OrdererOrgs = data['OrdererOrgs']
OrdererOrgs['Name'] = input('What is Orderer name? ')
OrdererOrgs['Domain'] = input('What is Orderer Domain? ')
OrdererOrgs['EnableNodeOUs'] = input('EnableNodeOUs? True or not? ')
OrdererOrgs['Hostname'] = input('What is hostname? ')

with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, stream=outfile, default_flow_style=False, indent=3)
```

This is the error:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: The error points it out clearly: `OrdererOrgs` is a list, and therefore its elements can only be accessed by an integer index try `OrdererOrgs[0]['Name'] = input('What is Orderer name? ')`

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for show a **text**. Instead, copy paste the **text** directly into the question post. See also [ask].